# ionic adding platform "warning: Insecure world writable dir"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods, ionic4

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin20/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/kalemmacbookpro/Desktop/coding/v5 in PATH, mode 040707`

when i am adding new platform for ios in my ionic project, i am getting this and my plugin is not working. i have tried some `chmod` examples but still same.
Please help me , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo chmod -R go-w /Users/kalemmacbookpro
```